# What is the rate limit for UserProperties?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am parsing a large text file and then calling a rate-limited Google API (mail migration) (The api docs state 1 second per call).

Even when I have Utilities.sleep(1000); inside my loop, I'm still getting this error even though I'm only setting the property one time during the loop:

> Service invoked too many times in a short time: properties rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls. (line 146)

Other than not setting the properties that often, what can I do to alleviate this?  Should I instead try to use the CacheService to store my property transiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the exact short term rate limits aren't exposed. You may want to try to increase your sleep amount, in the hopes of going above the threshold necessary to avoid the error. Ultimately I think your analysis is correct, that you should look into writing to the user properties less often. I'm not sure the CacheService is the right solution, but it depends on how you are using the information.

Comment: Thanks.  I was using the UserProperties to record a status of where in the file the parsing/migrating was occurring.  I wanted to record this in case of the Script spontaneously failing (and status getting lost) and also so a "status" report can be up-to-date on demand.  I think I'll instead only update it every 2-3 entries instead of on every one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the design of your app. If you are parsing the information and can aggregate that into a summary it would take less calls. Maybe sending as an email is not optimal. Could the parsed data go somewhere else and then direct the user there instead of sending emails?

Comment: The purpose of the application is to upload Lotus Notes based "structured export" mail exports to the Google Apps E-mail Migration API.  Essentially to allow users to migrate their e-mail from Lotus Notes on their own time and from different types/locations of archives than are supported by the official migration tool.  Regardless, e-mail is not the issue here.  I'm trying to track the progress (through setting UserProperties) of a long running process that can fail (parsing related error).

Answer (score 0):

properties v CacheService

CacheService produces the same error (Unless I have a bug in my code that I missed). If it helps CacheService lets you store longer strings, so this can reduce the number of writes.